# MySQL Query Painter

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a client who is very used to the MS Access query tool. I am migrating all of his data into MySQL.

Any recommendations for a User Friendly query painter I could provide him to be able to paint up his queries rather than type up SQL code?

Answer (score 4):

Why can't he just use Access with ODBC linked tables?

The usual answer for MySQL is [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), though. I use it for a number of websites I manage and I think it's quite nice as a management tool (though the querying tools are not nearly as well-developed as Access's).

Answer (score -1):

MySQL has an official MySQL Workbench:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

From the docs:

> MySQL Workbench provides DBAs and developers an integrated tools environment for:
>
> - Database Design & Modeling
> - SQL Development (replacing MySQL Query Browser)
> - Database Administration (replacing MySQL Administrator)
> - Database Migration